# How could I import google analytics data to Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-analytics, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataflow

I need to import data from **Google Analytics** to Google Cloud Platform (Cloud Storage maybe) and then process this information and exported to google cloud SQL.

I have not a clear idea what Google Cloud Service I can use to run the process of importing the data.

I was thinking to use **Google DataFlow** to do the Extraction Transformation and Load into **Cloud SQL**.

Comment: But if you are on GA Premium, you can always connect it to Google Big Query! Doesn't that help ?

Comment: @Tushar Yes I have read that there  is that option but we currently not have GA Premium at the moment.

Comment: If you had a way to export data from Google Analytics to any of the Google Cloud storage products, Apache Beam/Dataflow would be able to ingest that into Cloud SQL, e.g. using JdbcIO. However, I believe the only way to export raw data from GA is GA Premium (currently called GA 360).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jkff mentioned in the comments if you have Google Analytics 360 you can enable the bigQuery integration and your raw data will be exported daily to BigQuery.

If you don't then there's no way to export raw data easily.

You could try to run some queries on the API to extract data and create jobs to load this data into BigQuery or some other storage. But you'll run into multiple problems with this. Beyond the actual architecture of the system to run the ETL, your queries can only return specific reports, you can't run a query to export everything. So you'll have to figure out what data you need and export that specific report, and then repeat.

Comment: That is exactly what I need to run some queries on the **GA API** and get some specific data into the Google Cloud Platform, transform it using Cloud Dataflow and send it to BigQuery. But I don't know exactly how to do the part of extracting the data from GA to GCP. Any Clue how ??

Answer (score 0):

onlyGA 360 can export data, not for standard GA